# Why can't I install package yaml-mode on my Emacs via use-package declaration?

Tags: package, use-package, syntax-highlighting, package-repositories, install

I am trying to install a package called `yaml-mode` on my Emacs. Basically, a syntax highlighting for `.yaml` files. My current syntax highlighters do not have support for yaml files, apparently.

Hence, I added the following in my `init.el` file:

```lisp
;; Trying to install yaml-mode
(use-package yaml-mode
  :ensure t)
```

Unfortunately, after re-starting Emacs, I got the following error message:

> Error (use-package): Failed to install yaml-mode: https://melpa.org/packages/yaml-mode-20220903.1821.el: Not found Disable showing Disable logging
> Error (use-package): Cannot load yaml-mode Disable showing Disable logging

Although it mentions not being able to use MELPA, I can see `yaml-mode` package on MELPA repository [here](https://melpa.org/#/yaml-mode).

I would like to keep using `use-package` since it helps to make my init file declarative and more reproducible. This is [my whole init file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el), in case it is relevant.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do `package-refresh-contents` and try again.  Your package cache is probably out of date.

Comment: Thanks. After your suggestion, the error message changed. I have updated my question.

Comment: Oh, it was just a small typo after I commented-out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Professor [Fran Burstall](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/10465/fran-burstall) suggested executing the command `package-refresh-contents` as a comment in my original post. I executed his suggestion and now things work as expected. Thank you.